# Stop the function and callback instead of throwing error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a huge parsing function, if the file is correct, it work well, but I can t handle error correctly.

```
function parse (pathname, callback){
    //Some variables

    fs.open(pathname, 'r', function(err, fd){
        if (err){console.log('Error Opening the file'); callback(-1);}
        console.log('Begin the parsing');
        //Do the parsing
```

But if I give a invalid pathname, I get the message of Error, and the function continue until a fatal error when reading.

I thought callback was ending the function, but it seem I m wrong.

I could do something like:

```
function parse (pathname, callback){
    //Some variables

    fs.open(pathname, 'r', function(err, fd){
        if (err){console.log('Error Opening the file'); callback(-1);}
        else{
            console.log('Begin the parsing');
            //Do the parsing
```

But there s a lot of error handling in it, and the function is quite huge.

In other s code I usually see

```
if (err){throw err;}
```

But I never suceed in doing anything, even simple, with event, so I d like to avoid this too, and if I don t handle it, it end up closing the app, wich I don t want too.

Is there a neat way to let me handle the error in another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the function `parse` return which will interrupt the function execution.

```
if (err) {
    console.log('Error opening the file');
    callback(-1);
    return; // Alternatively return false or anything you want
}
```

Calling `callback(-1)` does not end the function since it is a simple function call just like `console.log()` or any other function.

Comment: Simple and working, I ll accept your answer in the end of the 2min limit